# I'm trying to add key,value to properties, it does not work. help me, please

Tags: java, properties, key-value

I am trying to add key, value to properties, It does not save.

Please help me!

```
Properties message_properties=new Properties();  
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/messages.properties");
message_properties.load(is);
message_properties.setProperty("key1", "value1");
message_properties.store(outputStream,null);
```

Comment: You need to tell us what has gone wrong? Otherwise how can we help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, "it does not work" does not shed any light on what zour problem is. Please do read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the type of  message_property

Comment: Where did `outputStream` come from?  Where do you close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use inputStream to read the properties file and outputStream to write to the file.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

//read using input stream
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file location");
prop.load(in);
in.close();

//set property
prop.setProperty("key","value");

//store using output stream
prop.store(new FileOutputtream("File_Location");
```